# Do school uniforms improve student behavior?

Tags: education, children, clothing, causality

Many of the advocates of school uniforms claim that uniforms for students in K-12 [reduce behavior problems such as bullying](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-467353/School-uniform-improves-pupils-behaviour-school.html).

What evidence exists to support or contradict these claims?

For example, it's fair to say that students are less likely to be bullied on the basis of clothing when everyone wears the same thing. But does overall bullying reduce with uniforms in the absence of any other changes? How about other behavioral or academic changes?

Comment: You can still bully the kids that don't have an iPhone, and anecdotally it was relied to me that girls make up for the lack of individualism by excessive use of makeup...

Comment: I've restricted your question to a single claim as it was too wide and generic.

Comment: "How do you measure and compare behaviour?" If fewer students are involved in medical complications due to actions from other students, that's probably a good first approximation. Grades and test achievement are probably a second.

Comment: Isn't all the real quality bullying done online these days?

Comment: @Werner and others: I've removed the whining. Please move on to the chat.

Comment: This [well-publicised study](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-467353/School-uniform-improves-pupils-behaviour-school.html) in the UK said there was improved behaviour, the fact that the research was sponsored by the Schoolwear Association was not so well-known.

Comment: One thing should be clear: although it would drastically reduce the chances of someone getting bullied due to his/her clothing, there are various other reasons for getting bullied. Secondly, if you look at most students who wear uniform, they don't exactly adhere to school rules. Students have their own way of jazzing the uniform up to make it look 'unique', unless the school rules are extremely strict. Maybe wear a cardigan, change the hairstyle, wear make-up, wear jewellery, etc. Academically it's fine to say there would be improvement, because the student won't be spending as much time dres

Comment: @neetprep or maybe they'll spend even more time trying to make their uniform look unique, who knows.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Reading around this subject there appears to have been a 1998 summary in the US which is quoted a lot in political debates [full report here.](http://www.members.tripod.com/rockqu/uniform.htm). This research summarised that

> Our findings indicate that student uniforms have no direct effect on
>   substance use, behavioral problems or attendance. A negative effect of
>   uniforms on student academic achievement was found

Which seems to be opposite to the prevailing wisdom about uniform promoting good behaviour.
There is also a study from 1998 study Into things which effect behaviour ins schools with a specific section on schools that can be found [here](http://www.keystosaferschools.com/Reports/Order%20in%20the%20Classroom-Violence,%20Discipline.pdf).
This study also concluded

> The notions that school uniforms and zero tolerance for gangs would
>   reduce school disorder and consequently improve student academic
>   performance were not supported

Looking for contraindications to the above evidence there is an article quoted around a bit from psychology today which indicated [that uniforms had a *huge* positive impact.](http://www.psychologytoday.com/articles/199909/uniform-improvements)

However I suspect there is a correlation not the direct causality indicated there (but without paying I can't access the full article). Indeed one of the quotes from people associated with the schools said this

> Dick Van Der Laan of the Long Beach Unified School District explained,
>   "We can't attribute the improvement exclusively to school uniforms,
>   but we think it's more than coincidental."

I think this quote highlights one of the problems with researching the issue of school uniforms. School's do not exist in a vacuum, and a whole host of things change from term to term when there is a problem with behaviour in an attempt to sort out issues.

It is difficult to tell whether benefits are anything to do with the school uniform itself, or other reforms which happened around the same time. One can also guess that schools with strict dress policies and/or uniform policies will also be more strict on behavioural terms (just being consistent) so any study just considering uniforms may be skewed.

Anecdotal evidence is available on the department of education website [too](http://ed.gov/updates/uniforms.html). But there still seems to be a lack of direct evidence. It can be noted that this page indicates that schools should

> Treat school uniforms as part of an overall safety program
>   And not treat it as a single fix for anything.

Actual statistical comparisons seem to be thin on the ground apart from the first two studies, and most of the stuff I read calls for more studies, however I can see difficulties with producing comprehensive and verifiable information about the effect of uniforms in general.

Comment: It strikes me as entirely unsurprising that school uniforms have a negative impact on performance.  Certainly I perform better if I'm comfortable in the clothes I wear.